# Show custom type taxonomy overview page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom type `documentaries` and a taxonomy for it `documentary_category`. If I navigate to /documentaries, I see an archive page which I tweaked a little bit in my child template by adding archive-documentaries.php.

I want to show a page with a hierarchical structure of all terms under `documentary_category`.
The first question I have is, to what URL am I supposed to navigate?
I tried navigating to /documentary_category & /documentaries/documentary_category but both give me a Not Found.

I also tried adding a template file to my child theme `taxonomy-documentary_category.php` which also results in a Not Found.

Wordpress version: 5.4
Custom types pugin: CPT UI
Custom fields plugin: ACF
Theme: Twenty Twenty

CPT

```
{
  "documentaries": {
    "name": "documentaries",
    "label": "Documentaries",
    "singular_label": "Documentary",
    "description": "",
    "public": "true",
    "publicly_queryable": "true",
    "show_ui": "true",
    "show_in_nav_menus": "true",
    "delete_with_user": "false",
    "show_in_rest": "true",
    "rest_base": "",
    "rest_controller_class": "",
    "has_archive": "true",
    "has_archive_string": "",
    "exclude_from_search": "false",
    "capability_type": "post",
    "hierarchical": "true",
    "rewrite": "true",
    "rewrite_slug": "",
    "rewrite_withfront": "true",
    "query_var": "true",
    "query_var_slug": "",
    "menu_position": "",
    "show_in_menu": "true",
    "show_in_menu_string": "",
    "menu_icon": "",
    "supports": [
      "title",
      "thumbnail",
      "excerpt",
      "custom-fields",
      "comments",
      "page-attributes"
    ],
    "taxonomies": [
      "documentary_category"
    ],
    "labels": {
      "menu_name": "",
      "all_items": "",
      "add_new": "",
      "add_new_item": "",
      "edit_item": "",
      "new_item": "",
      "view_item": "",
      "view_items": "",
      "search_items": "",
      "not_found": "",
      "not_found_in_trash": "",
      "parent_item_colon": "",
      "featured_image": "",
      "set_featured_image": "",
      "remove_featured_image": "",
      "use_featured_image": "",
      "archives": "",
      "insert_into_item": "",
      "uploaded_to_this_item": "",
      "filter_items_list": "",
      "items_list_navigation": "",
      "items_list": "",
      "attributes": "",
      "name_admin_bar": "",
      "item_published": "",
      "item_published_privately": "",
      "item_reverted_to_draft": "",
      "item_scheduled": "",
      "item_updated": ""
    },
    "custom_supports": ""
  }
}
```

Taxonomy

```
{
  "documentary_category": {
    "name": "documentary_category",
    "label": "Documentary categories",
    "singular_label": "Documentary category",
    "description": "",
    "public": "true",
    "publicly_queryable": "true",
    "hierarchical": "true",
    "show_ui": "true",
    "show_in_menu": "true",
    "show_in_nav_menus": "true",
    "query_var": "true",
    "query_var_slug": "",
    "rewrite": "false",
    "rewrite_slug": "",
    "rewrite_withfront": "1",
    "rewrite_hierarchical": "1",
    "show_admin_column": "false",
    "show_in_rest": "true",
    "show_in_quick_edit": "",
    "rest_base": "",
    "rest_controller_class": "",
    "labels": {
      "menu_name": "",
      "all_items": "",
      "edit_item": "",
      "view_item": "",
      "update_item": "",
      "add_new_item": "",
      "new_item_name": "",
      "parent_item": "",
      "parent_item_colon": "",
      "search_items": "",
      "popular_items": "",
      "separate_items_with_commas": "",
      "add_or_remove_items": "",
      "choose_from_most_used": "",
      "not_found": "",
      "no_terms": "",
      "items_list_navigation": "",
      "items_list": ""
    },
    "meta_box_cb": "",
    "object_types": [
      "documentaries"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the custom post register code you used to add the new post type and taxonomy?

Comment: @kaize I added the plugin export code

Comment: Try to add  `"has_archive"   => "true",` after the `"hierarchical": "true",` or anywhere else but not in labels at the taxonomy part. Then the custom archive you've made should work

Comment: I achieved this by importing the same json with the has_archive entry added to it. The template still doesn't load.